# Why do I have different apps on top-level-site and subsite?

Tags: sharepoint-online, app

Why do I have different options on the apps on my top-level-site and my subsite? And can I get the apps somehow to my subsite?

Comment: which site you are talking about, is it team site on both level? or team site collection with publishing subsite or reverse?

Comment: Team site collection with publishing subsite

Answer (score 0):

Your sites probably have different features activated.  Some features provide the ability to create certain apps.  Team Collaboration Lists and the various Project site features are some of these.  Some of these features may require a site collection feature to be activated.  [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/razi/archive/2013/10/28/listing-all-sharepoint-2013-features-including-name-title-scope-id-and-description.aspx) is a list of all SharePoint features. I'll try to find a list that displays the ones available in SPO.